# How do I render page in IE9 as IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, rendering, meta-tags

I am trying to render a page in IE9 as IE8, as I am seeing some strange rendering in IE9 which I am not sure how to sort out at the moment. I am using this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

But I am still seeing the rendering issue in IE9, which I don't see in IE8.  You should be able to see the issue in IE9 on this page [here](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/conference/index.html).  The rounded corner blocks generated by a plugin aren't rendering properly.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to what else I can try?

Comment: IE9 supports rounded corners natively using the CSS `border-radius` style, so you shouldn't need a plugin for them except for IE8 and lower (in which case, I strongly recommend [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact behaviour of an IE version there is no substitute to using that version. Tools like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) will let you install and run several versions side-by-side or an even more accurate (but less convenient) method is to use a virtual machine with an image for different versions of IE.

You could also try looking at the plugin itself. Perhaps it's using browser sniffing or IE conditional comments to detect the IE version.

As a general rule though if you have to resort to X-UA-Compatible you're probably doing something wrong. It's a nasty hack for a nasty browser and in the long run you would be better off designing around it (or leave the rounded corners stuff to the browsers that support it natively).